# ObservableCollection causing a lot of GC Pressure

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

I am using Livecharts2 in my WPF Application in order to show a realtime graph (100 data points/s)

The chart is connected to an ObservableCollection.
I found that my Code to add DataPoints is causing a lot of GC Pressure:
[image]

The Code to add Data is as follows:

```
// amount of datapoints to keep in chart per series 
// (200 points / 25points per second = 8 seconds)
static int dataLength = 200;
// 4 series in total
private static List<ObservableCollection<ObservableValue>> seriesDataPoints 
    = new List<ObservableCollection<ObservableValue>>();
private static List<string> seriesNames = new List<string>();
// variable in attempt to reduce GC pressure
private static ObservableValue ReUseShell = null;
// add new datapoint (and remove old datapoint if series > dataLength )
public static void AddDataPoint(double point, string seriesName)
{
    // search for the correct series
    int seriesIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < seriesNames.Count; i++)
    {
        if (seriesNames[i] == seriesName)
        {
            seriesIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // series was not found, create new serries
    if (seriesIndex == -1)
    {
        seriesIndex = CreateNewSeries(seriesName);
    }
    // check if we have a reusable datapoint (in order to reduce gc)
    if (ReUseShell != null)
    {
        ReUseShell.Value = point;
        seriesDataPoints[seriesIndex].Add(ReUseShell);
        ReUseShell = null;
    }
    else
    { // we dont have a empty data point (series < datalengt / ~initialisation)
        seriesDataPoints[seriesIndex].Add(new(point));
    }
    // remove oldest datapoint and reuse it for the next data fill
    if (seriesDataPoints[seriesIndex].Count > dataLength)
    {
        ReUseShell = seriesDataPoints[seriesIndex][0];
        seriesDataPoints[seriesIndex].RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

and this is how the chart looks:
[image]

Is there any issue with my code / Observable collection or does the issue reside with the Library LiveCharts2?

Comment: When creating custom controls whether it is XAML, WinForms or anything, avoid the usual binding/observable traps offered by such frameworks as they **don't** scale to the level needed for high-performance data visualisations.  Instead, render directly to an offscreen bitmap/raster/buffer and blit the results to the screen in one go.  More than likely your WPF chart "control" inherits from `UIElement` which contains slow elements such as _layout_ making it unsuitable for render-to-buffer operations.  Consider using a `DrawingContext` to render directly to a `DrawingVisual`

Comment: ....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: You need to analize which types in managed heaps you have.. probably you have a lot of objects in Gen2.. and GC can't release enough space and start each time more and more.  What is ObservableValue.. it seems to custom type.. and probably it can be referenced from different places. At least need to check that it implement INotifyPropertyChanges.